# Template construct... it works, but feels ugly

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

In a template I am showing the first 5 translations of an item (i). The following logic is handled in the template:

- If there are more than 5 translations: I trim the list and show a
  link `more...`.
- If there are 1 to 5 translations: I simply show them.
- If there is no translation: I show a link to add a translation.

Here is the (functional) template code I came up with:

```
{% if i.translation_set.all %}
    <ul>
    {% for t in i.translation_set.all|slice:"6" %}
        {% if forloop.counter < 6 %}
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-play mr-2"></i>
                {{ t.language }}
                <i class="fa fa-commenting-o ml-1"></i>
            </a>
        </li>
        {% else %}
            <li>more...</li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'view-item' i_id=i.id slug=i.slug %}">Add translation</a>
{% endif %}
```

Here are my concerns regarding this code:

- What sort of query is executed for `if i.translation_set.all`? Does it query all translations or does it stop at 1?
- Is it maybe better to use the same `slice` query, since that gets used later and could be (automatically?) cached?
- It feels ugly to query 6 items, while only needing to display max 5. Is there another way to tell there are more than 5 items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{% if i.translation_set.all %}
```

If you are not looping over the queryset later, then you should avoid doing `{% if i.translation_set.all %}`, as it will fetch all the translations from the database. An improvement would be to use `exists` instead.

```
{% if i.translation_set.exists %}
```

Even better, you could use the `{% with tag %}` to fetch the sliced queryset. Then you can use the sliced queryset in the if statement and loop over it.

```
{% with translations=i.translation_set.all|slice:"6" %}
{% if translations %}
<ul>
    {% for t in translations %}
    ...
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
...
{% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

An alternative to fetching 6 objects in the slice would be to fetch the count as a separate query. Then you can limit the slice to 5 objects.

```
{% with translation_count=i.translation_set.count %}
{% if translations_count %}
<ul>
    {% for t in translations|slice:"5" %}
    ...
    {% endfor %}
    {% if t.count > 5 %}
      <li>more...</li>
    {% endif %}
</ul>
...
{% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

This uses two queries instead of one, but you might prefer it if you find it clearer. In practice, the extra query will probably make no difference to performance.

Comment: Why is the `{% with %}` tag regarded better (in this case) than a direct `{% for %}` loop? edit: I see now, you can use it in the `{% if %}` as well. Does make for clearer code, yes.

Comment: Exactly - by using the `{% with %}` tag, you can use the queryset in `{% if %}` tags and loop over it, and it will only be fetched from the database once.

Comment: Yes, I was actually trying to figure out how to store the queryset in a variable. Seems like this solves it elegantly. I decided to go with fetching 6 results as the code seems obvious enough.